# How would I see if two Java queues are equal on the basis of the value of the contents of each?

Tags: java, collections, equals

I want to implement an override of equals that compares two Java Queue objects on the basis of them each having contents that are equal (by value).

I can probably hack together some code, but surely someone has solved this elegantly already. A google search didn't turn up any results, so I came here next.

I appreciate any suggestions. I'm going to need to do the same thing with ArrayList and HashMap collections too.

BTW, for equals(), I using this as my guide: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17

It gives some hints, but apparently I need more help when it comes to the collections. The types contained in the collections are overriding equals() based on the recommendations from that link.

Comment: is this homework?  if not, how have you approached it?

Comment: Haha. Is my question really that bad? This is a real question from a guy who has been out of school for many years!

Comment: @SB - apparently it wasn't as simple as you thought after all. See mhaller's reply. I don't feel quite as bad for asking the question now. :)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it was a bad question.  but the accepted answer just uses .equals on ArrayList and then uses Arrays.equals (which your link has an example of) and references JavaDocs on a Queue.  If the question were bad, it would have been closed by the community.  Don't feel bad for asking anything here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JavaDoc of java.util.Queue already states the problem:

> Queue implementations generally do not define element-based versions of methods equals and hashCode but instead inherit the identity based versions from class Object, because element-based equality is not always well-defined for queues with the same elements but different ordering properties.

So, you need to implement the logic on your own (or reuse some library) for your use-cases, if you want to do it based on the contained objects.

E.g. for an ArrayList, you would just call `ArrayList.equals()`.

For the queues, I would go for a pragmatic approach of converting them to an array using e.g. `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.toArray()` and then use `Arrays.equals(queue1AsArray,queue2AsArray);`

Comment: Thank you. I was not having the expected results from Queue containsAll, so I will try your suggestion. In addition, I appear to be having trouble comparing dates. 

Here's the code I'm using to compare dates:
(this.timestamp.compareTo(that.timestamp) == 0). It gives the unexpected result: timestamp: Tue Nov 16 19:05:53 EST 2010==Tue Nov 16 19:05:53 EST 2010 : false

Comment: The date comparison problem was due to loss of precision after serialization/deserialization. That's resolved now (by comparing date strings). And the Arrays.equals() suggestion you made is working. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of comparing date strings, consider comparing at lower resolution (e.g. compare after masking off the X lower order bits), or use a Calendar object (shudder).  Dates-in-strings is rarely the way to go.  That said, I'm quite surprised that serialization would have caused a loss of precision (unless you are customizing the serialization of the long somehow)